# How to get my email to send from outlook after switching to Frontier service provider

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp, isp

I have recently moved to a new location and brought my computer with me, naturally. I purchased internet service through Frontier and figured that my POP email on Outlook, through secureserver.net, would be unaffected. I thought I would just be able to plug it in and it would work.

But it doesn't work! I can still receive emails, but I cannot send anything. It continually tells me that it cannot connect to the SMTP server. It shows me error code 0x80042109.

I'm not sure what to do. I have fiddled with the settings, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is likely the port that you are using. [Frontier has blocked port 25](http://www.frontierhelp.com/faq.cfm?qstid=228), the most commonly used port for SMTP, in an effort to minimize spam.

You should only have to change the port number to something else that your email provider can use. They usually have several options available for occasions such as this.

[SecureServer.net, the email provider you use, offers you ports 25, 80, or 3535.](http://help.securepaynet.net/article/4715) Since Frontier is blocking port 25, give the other two a try. You probably won't need to change any other settings.

Here are the steps to change the port for any email account in Outlook 2010:<sup>*</sup>

[image: Click File > Info > Account Settings]
[image: Click Account Settings drop down]
[image: Highlight the email account then click Change]
[image: Click more settings near the bottom to the right]
[image: Click the Advanced tab then cha]

Click OK to close that window. Then click Next or Cancel (a little counter-intuitive, but it will still save your settings if you click Cancel).

If the port was the problem it, should now work without any issue.

---

<sup>* [Frontier has directions for similar tasks for the other major Outlook versions.](http://www.frontierhelp.com/usertoolscategories.cfm?mcatid=28)</sup>